# How to define a Table in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

When creating a HDInsight On Demand Linked Resource, the Data Factory creates a new container for the hdinsight. I wonder to know how I can creates a Table that points to that container? Here is my Table definition

```
{
"name": "AzureBlobLocation",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureBlobLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "folderPath": "????/Folder1/Folder2/Output/Aggregation/",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat"
        }
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 1
    }
}
}
```

What should goes instead of '????' that I put in there? the keyword  in not accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use the keyword 'container' in order to point to the working container.